# How to access attributes using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, builder

I have a simple task of accessing the values of some attributes. This is a simple script that uses `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` to create a simple XML doc.

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Placement(:messageId => "392847-039820-938777", :system => "MOD", :version => "2.0") {
    xml.objects {
        xml.object(:myattribute => "99", :anotherattrib => "333")
        xml.nextobject_ '9387toot'
        xml.Entertainment "Last Man Standing"
    }
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
puts builder.root.attributes["messageId"]
```

The results are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Placement messageId="392847-039820-938777" version="2.0" system="MOD">
  <objects>
    <object anotherattrib="333" myattribute="99"/>
    <nextobject>9387toot</nextobject>
    <Entertainment>Last Man Standing</Entertainment>
  </objects>
</Placement>
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:178:in `add_child': Document already has a root node (RuntimeError)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:455:in `parent='
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/builder.rb:358:in `insert'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/xml/builder.rb:350:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Documents and Settings/etrojan/workspace/Lads/tryXPATH2.rb:15
```

The XML that is generated looks fine. However, my attempts to access attributes cause an error to be generated:

```
Document already has a root node
```

I don't understand why `puts` would cause this error.

Answer (score 72):

Using [Nokogiri::XML::Reader](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Reader.html) works for your example, but probably isn't the full answer you are looking for (Note that there is [no `attributes` method for Builder](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)).

```
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(builder.to_xml)
reader.read #Moves to next node in document
reader.attribute("messageId")
```

Note that if you issued `reader.read` again and then tried `reader.attribute("messageId")` the result will be `nil` since the current node will not have this attribute.

What you probably want to do is use [Nokogiri::XML::Document](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html) if you want to search an XML document by attribute.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(builder.to_xml)
elems = doc.xpath("//*[@messageId]") #get all elements with an attribute of 'messageId'
elems[0].attr('messageId') #gets value of attribute of first elem
```

Comment: Great stuff, this helped me out at 2:22am during an all weekend codefest. Gracias.

Comment: I looked @ this code
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/finding-elements-attributes and was breaking my head because I was using the @ outside [. This has been a real saviour. I have wasted 2 days to figure out a way to parse xml attributes and this is a true saviour. It will be nice if this link added to nokogiri

Comment: you can use xpath to get attributes value  `nokogiri_element.xpath("@id").text()`

Comment: Using [`doc.at_xpath`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#at_xpath-instance_method) would achieve the same thing as `elems[0]`. `doc.at_xpath("//*[@messageId]")['messageId']` would be simpler.

Answer (score 55):

Here is a slightly more succinct way to access attributes using `Nokogiri` (assuming you already have your xml stored in a variable called `xml`, as covered by @atomicules' answer):

```
xml.xpath("//Placement").attr("messageId")
```