# Select element by attribute value with XPath in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

So if I have this piece of code

```
<body>
  <div class="red">
    <a href="http://www.example.com>Example</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

I know that I want to get an element with the attribute "class" and value "red" but I don't know where is located.

If I used XPath, is this piece of code right?

```
dir = "http://www.domain.com"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.xpath('.//*[class="red"]')
```

I'm just learning so I don't know if any of this is wrong. I can't make it work. Thanks.

Edit: Now it's working =)

```
doc.xpath('//*[@class="red"]')
```

Comment: it should be @class. Initial *dot* doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901241/how-to-access-attributes-using-nokogiri

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change class to @class. Remove the dot in the beginning. Then it will work.