# Can I get value of an specific attribute only by XPath?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a code like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<a href='foo.html'>foo</a><a href='bar.html'>bar</a>")
doc.xpath('//a/@href').map(&:value) # => ["foo.html", "bar.html"]
```

It works as I expected.

But just out of curiosity I want to know, can I also get the value of `href` attributes only by using XPath?

Comment: What do you mean `only by using XPath`? This `//a/@href` is `XPath` to get `href` attribute value. http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ca%20href%3D%27foo.html%27%3Efoo%3C%2Fa%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%27bar.html%27%3Ebar%3C%2Fa%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fa%2F%40href&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath3

Comment: I thought maybe there is a xpath something like `//a/@href/value()`. It seems there isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate attributes first

example: 
site name:
https://www.easymobilerecharge.com/

We want to locate "MTS" link

In your case, to locate this element, we can use x-path like:
**//a[contains(text(),'MTS')]**

Now to get  href attribute, use:
**//a[contains(text(),'MTS')]/@href**

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901241/how-to-access-attributes-using-nokogiri) the answer seems to be yes and no. It offers

```
xml.xpath("//Placement").attr("messageId")
```

which is quite close to "only XPath", but not entirely. Up to you to judge if that is enough for you.